# AccountQueryRq (qbxml) throwing error when parsing the provided XML text stream

Tags: php, quickbooks, qbxml

I am using Keith's Consolibyte PHP SDK for QBXML to fetch the data from QB Desktop (US 2022 version). I have 2 client company files on two different machines (2 different QB Desktop instances. both same version as above). When I request Accounts import using qbxml (below) then one QB instance returns proper data(all account details as xml response) where as the same xml fails for the other QB instance with error message as below.

XML:

```
<?qbxml version="13.0"?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError"><AccountQueryRq requestID="22471"></AccountQueryRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>
```

Error:

```
QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.
```

I am not able to understand why this error is coming only on one QB instance where as the same is returning complete account details as xml response on other QB instance. Request some pointer on it as what could be the reason for the problem. There is no difference in the input QBXML (except the request ID which is automatically generated by the QBXML SDK).

I have tested the same using qbxml tester(SDKTestPLus3) too. Everything related to webconnector, qwc file permission is all correctely set. PLease guide me on this.

Thanks,